# How can i style an embed to take its title, description, and thumbnail from a particular webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, webhooks, discord.py

i'm working on a discord bot in python-rewrite. And i have a nsfw command called crimson, that first checks if the channel is a nsfw channel if it is, it posts a link to a nsfw comic.

Now i want to set it so that it posts the link as an embed but when i add the link to the embed it doesnt add the tags or the thumbnail into the embed. Which i want it to retrieve that from the posted link. Here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSqgm.jpg something like this.

The title as a link, the tags of the comic as the description, and a picture of the comic all taken from the website posted by the bot is there a way i could do that. I was thinking one way to do it might be as a webhook but im not too sure.

Here is my current code,

```
@client.command()
async def crimson(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.is_nsfw():
        e = discord.Embed(url="https://nhentai.net/g/176455/", color=0x32CD32)
        await ctx.send(embed=e)

    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="ARE YOU INSANE THIS CHANNEL IS A SFW CHANNEL!!", color=0xDC143C)
        embed.set_image(url="https://www.anime-planet.com/images/characters/romani-archaman-119364.jpg?t=1483745959")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I've looked into doing it as a webhook, as well looking a various embed questions but i cant figure how i would obtain the tags as the description and the image on the webpage as the image in the embed

Currently it has the color i want and the link in the embed but i cant figure out how to obtain the tags and image from the link.

Comment: One way would be to use beautiful soup to download the page and parse all of that information out of it to form the embed.  It's also possible that that site exposes a metadata API that could be used for gathering that information.  Unfortunately, embeds aren't very "smart", they don't automatically generate themselves the way you';re looking for.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh i see so basically beautifulsoup shows you all the contents of the webpage where it gets everything? I just checked the webpage and i saw that if i inspect it i can select each url of the page individually as each property is a meta. Excluding the tags which i can add as regular text in the description.

Comment: Beautiful soup will take html files and turn them into Python data structures that you can easily interact with as objects in your code.  If you're trying to copy/extend the functionality of some other bot, you can check to see if it's open source and just read it's code to see how they do it.  DOn't copy anything without reading their license though.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh i tried using beautifulsoup and i was getting an error in the html file so now what im trying to do is split each part into seperate arrays and set it up so that when the random.choice selects an index in the first array the second and third array selects the same index in their arrays via a for loop but im not a complete expert on for loops so im trying to figure that out now

Comment: first array is the link second array the tags or description of the embed and the third the image